# How to do authentication with PGP asymmetric encryption?

Tags: encryption, pgp, encryption-symmetric

I'm writing a message and encrypting it for my recipients with a PGP data encryption model.

How should the signing process by me, the sender, and authentication by the receivers work **only for authentication** purposes?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "only for authentication purposes"? Authentication of what / who? Why would the signing process *not* work for that? What is is that you do not understand? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Note too that stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. There is superuser for command line usage and the IT security site for security related questions.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Gotcha. But eventually it's a programming question because I want to understand how to program it :) No? What I'm missing?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I'm trying to achieve the ability of me, signing a data (with what?) and the receiver to authenticate that it's comes from me.

Comment: Signing works the same with PGP as with other cryptography. The sender has a keypair, and signs using her private key. The receivers' must have a copy of the sender's public key and can use this to verify the message. The receiver also needs some mechanism to trust that the public key really belongs to you and not a man-in-the-middle. There are several mechanisms to accomplish this.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Great. So the receiver, with his public key, will do ~what~ on the data signed by the sender with his private key? Because "Verify" is a general term, right?

Comment: "verify" is a technical term of art in public key cryptography. Really, tutorial-type questions are just not a good fit for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to provided **authentication** and **not confidentiality** of the data, the data sender will **encrypting his message using a private key** and everyone who will decrypt the message using the sender's public key, that we can assume known to everyone, will know his identity.